# PowerMockito error: Cannot access Stubber/IOngoingStubbing

Tags: powermockito

The IDE compiler shows these errors when using PowerMockito.

I tried both variants for specifying return values:

**Variant 1**

```
  doReturn(jsonString).when(MyStaticClass.myStaticMethod());
```

[image]

**Variant 2**

```
  when(MyStaticClass.myStaticMethod()).thenReturn(jsonString);
```

[image]

Why do the compiler display these errors?

Comment: What is wrong with my question for voting down?

Comment: I have exactly this issue and still haven't found an answer. No idea why people vote down on this.

Answer (score 1):

I used

```
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;
```

but you should use:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
```

Comment: Good question, I just found this in a working example.